# SP working on localhost but not on live server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I have created a SP on SQL server:

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[proc_GetSalesProductWise] @ItemCode int,
                                         @year int,  
                                         @CustomerCode numeric(18,0),  
                                         @Month int,
                                         @DataFrom nvarchar(15) AS
BEGIN

SELECT ISNULL((SELECT SUM(Quantity)
               FROM QryBoutiqueSalesGraphProductWise
               WHERE ItemCode = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@ItemCode,0)=0 THEN ItemCode
                                     ELSE @ItemCode
                                END
                 AND YEAR(InvDate) = @year
                 AND Month(InvDate) = @Month
                 AND DataFrom = @DataFrom
                 AND CustomerCode = @CustomerCode
               GROUP BY ItemCode),0) AS Quantity,
        ISNULL((SELECT SUM(GrossAmount)
                FROM QryBoutiqueSalesGraphProductWise
                WHERE ItemCode = CASE WHEN ISNULL(@ItemCode,0)=0 THEN ItemCode
                                      ELSE @ItemCode
                                 END
                  AND YEAR(InvDate) = @year
                  AND Month(InvDate) = @Month
                  AND DataFrom = @DataFrom
                  AND CustomerCode = @CustomerCode
               GROUP BY ItemCode),0) AS Amount

END
```

It is working perfectly on Localhost but giving the following error on live site.

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Subquery returned more than 1 value. 
This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when 
the subquery is used as an expression.
```

Can anyone help me out of this or tell me whats the issue?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: What part of the error don't you understand? It's quite clear (in my opinion).

Comment: Is there any problem in the procedure?

Comment: jarlh I am using SQL Server

Comment: You'll get the error if more than one 'ItemCode' exists for the same year, month, and 'CustomerCode' for the data selected. This data condition apparently doesn't exist in your non-prod environments for the data selected. You can identify problem data with `SELECT ItemCode, year(InvDate) AS year, Month(InvDate) AS month, CustomerCode
FROM QryBoutiqueSalesGraphProductWise 
GROUP BY ItemCode, year(InvDate), Month(InvDate), CustomerCode
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here most of the chance SQL query return more than one rows if itemcode is more than onme is uniq :

```
select sum(Quantity)
from QryBoutiqueSalesGraphProductWise where ItemCode = CASE WHEN 
ISNULL(@ItemCode,0)=0 THEN ItemCode ELSE @ItemCode END
and year(InvDate) = @year and Month(InvDate) = @Month and DataFrom = 
@DataFrom and CustomerCode = @CustomerCode
group by ItemCode
```

and

```
select sum(GrossAmount)
from QryBoutiqueSalesGraphProductWise where ItemCode = CASE WHEN 
ISNULL(@ItemCode,0)=0 THEN ItemCode ELSE @ItemCode END
and year(InvDate) = @year and Month(InvDate) = @Month and DataFrom = 
@DataFrom and CustomerCode = @CustomerCode
```

## group by ItemCode

Please try with below :

```
  Create Proc [dbo].[proc_GetSalesProductWise]
    @ItemCode int,
    @year int,  
    @CustomerCode numeric(18,0),  
    @Month int,
    @DataFrom nvarchar(15)

    AS
    Begin
    select ItemCode, sum(ISNULL(Quantity,0)) as Quantity, 
    sum(ISNULL(GrossAmount,0)) as Amount
    from QryBoutiqueSalesGraphProductWise where ItemCode = CASE WHEN 
    ISNULL(@ItemCode,0)=0 THEN ItemCode ELSE @ItemCode END
    and year(InvDate) = @year and Month(InvDate) = @Month and DataFrom = 
    @DataFrom and CustomerCode = @CustomerCode
    group by ItemCode
END
```

Comment: You just beat me to it. :)

Comment: I made this proc earlier but when there is no data found for an Itemcode, the SP returns empty result. which I don't want. I want it to treturn ) when no record is found.

Comment: *I want it to return 0 when no record is found. That is why i used ISNULL

Answer (score -1):

Check Parameter value which you passed in sp.